# Identifying NoData pixels source in SoilGrids: current and legacy layers

Tags: soilgrids

I am trying to identify the origin of NoData pixels in the SoilGrids250 layers. i.e. I want to know which NoData pixels are inland water vs. sea water (the paper mentions using a sea mask) vs. permanent ice.

I am interested in both SoilGrids250 2017 (1.0) and SoilGrids250 2.0. This is because SoilGrids250 was used to make derived products for which I also need to identify inland water vs. sea water vs. permanent ice (e.g. [Ross et al. 2018](https://www.nature.com/articles/sdata201891)).

Are these layers available?

My understanding is that most of this processing (but not all) was performed using GlobeLand30 for SoilGrids 2017; but that website (http://www.globallandcover.com/User/Login.aspx) isn't functional for downloads (it's not possible to create a password + the forgot password page is down) and the emails of the data creators are invalid.

Note that I am specifically interested in identifying the pixels in the SoilGrids250 layers and not in improving upon these masks.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you want, if you want to identify the location of nodata pixels then the isnull() tool in arcmap will pulls those out into a binary raster.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the following in the [SoilGrids FAQ](https://www.isric.org/explore/soilgrids/faq-soilgrids#Which_soil_mask_map_was_used):

> For the current SoilGrids release, the global soil mask map was derived from the latest [ESA land cover map](http://maps.elie.ucl.ac.be/CCI/viewer/download/CCI-LC_Maps_Legend.pdf), with the classes Urban (code 190), inland water (code 210), glacier (code 220) and bare surface (code 200) masked out.

The mask itself is available from the [WebDAV service](https://files.isric.org/soilgrids/data/recent/landmask/).

Comment: Thank you for your response! This is already very helpful. I did not realize that SoilGrids 2.0 just came out. To reflect this, I updated my question to include both SoilGrids 1.0 and 2.0.